# Index from address in array of pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The code below a solution to the following requirement:

> "Change the representation of `Link` and `List` from §27.9 without changing the user interface provided by the functions. Allocate `Link`s in an array of `Links` and have the members: `first`, `last`, `prev`, and `next` be `int`s (indices into the array). "  
> - Exercise 6 Chapter 27 - Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ B. Stroustrup

The interface is inherited from an ordinary implementation of an **Intrusive** doubly linked list. I've added the bool array (and the associated functions) to keep track of memory:

```
 #include <iostream>

struct Link
{
    int next;
    int prev;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct List
{
    Link** head;
    int first;      // points to the current first node
    int last;

    bool* available;
    int list_size;

    int get_index()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list_size; ++i)
        {
            if (available[i] == true) 
            {
                available[i] = false;
                return i;
            }
        }
        throw std::bad_alloc("bla bla!\n");
    }

    List()
    {
        list_size = 30;

        head = new Link*[list_size];
        available = new bool[list_size];

        first = -1;
        last = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < list_size; ++i)
        {
            available[i] = true;
        }
    }

    void List::push_back(Link* l)
    {
        if (l == nullptr)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("bla bla!\n");
        }

        int index = get_index();
        head[index] = l;

        if (last != -1)
        {
            head[last]->next = index;
            head[index]->prev = last;
        }
        else
        {
           first = index;
           head[index]->prev = -1;
        }

        last = index;
        head[index]->next = -1;
    }

    void push_front(Link* l)
    {
        if (l == nullptr)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("bla bla\n");
        }

        int index = get_index();
        head[index] = l;

        if (first != -1)
        {
            head[first]->prev = index;
            head[index]->next = first;
        }
        else
        {
            last = index;
            head[index]->next = -1;
        }

        first = index;
        head[index]->prev = -1;
    }

    // index = ptr - base
    std::ptrdiff_t index_from_address(Link* l) { return l - head[0]; }

    Link* front() const { return head[first]; }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    List l;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        l.push_back(new Link());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        l.push_front(new Link());
    }

    std::cout <<"first = "<< l.first <<", index = " << l.index_from_address(l.front());
    getchar();
}
```

Expected result:

> `first = 19, index = 19`

Actual result:

> `first = 19, index = 194`

Why?

Comment: What did you find you with the debugger?

Comment: I have no idea what sort of data structure this is supposed to be.

Comment: Where do you initialize head[0] and head[first]?

Comment: Why does the first node have index 15? This code doesn't even make any sense.

Comment: @Ziezi: But you don't have an array of `Link`. You have an array of `Link*`.

Comment: to see 15 you will need to work on pointers to pointers: `std::ptrdiff_t index_from_address(Link** l) { return l - head; } Link** front() const { return &head[first]; }`, otherwise you work on uninitialized pointers

Comment: @MSalters Is it OK now?

Comment: @CodyGray I would have to admit that the "M" in MCVE was a bit abused.

Comment: @Ziezi: I'm still struggling to understand what the datastructure should be. You really, really should learn the C++ standard containers first (in particular `std::vector<>` and `std::list<>`). The two main things you should be able to tell us about your container type are (1) what does it contain and (2) what operations does it support?

Comment: @MSalters The above code is written as a solution to the following requirement: _" Change the representation of `Link` and `List` from §27.9 without changing the user interface provided by the functions. Allocate `Link`s in an array of `Link`s and have the members: `first`, `last`, `prev`, and `next` be `int`s (indices into the array).  "_. The interface is inherited from an ordinary implementation of a doubly linked list. I've added the `bool` array (and the associated functions) to keep track of memory.

Comment: @Ziezi: If your book is having these exercises before introducing `std::vector`, ditch the book and check the [C++ book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). It sounds horrible, both on the C++ side and the pedagogical side.

Comment: @MSalters Exercise 6 Chapter 27 - Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ B. Stroustrup. I'm just writing it in C++ first, and then in C.

Comment: @MSalters I don't know if I've understood you well, when you were mentioning `std` containers...anyway,  the memory management part will be placed in an allocator and separated from the List. This is just a first attempt.

Comment: @Ziezi: Well, that's a reasonable book from what I hear, and I'm pretty sure it covered `std::vector` before chapter 27.

Comment: @MSalters the whole point of the exercise (IMO) is to compare implementations of Intrusive vs Non-instrusive containers, and to underline the additional memory management needs of the latter case (associated with container of pointers).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146734/discussion-between-msalters-and-ziezi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> l - head[0]
> ```

Here you compare the *values* of the two pointers. You let all pointers in the array be default initialized, so their values are indeterminate, and therefore the behaviour of accessing the values is undefined.

You probably intended `index_from_address` to find the index where a  particular *pointer* object is stored - rather than the object that is pointed to, since the pointed to object is not in the array pointed by `head`. To do that, you must add a whole bunch of `&`:

```
 Link*& front() const // return a reference to the pointer object, not a copy

 //  take a reference to the pointer as an argument, add const for good measure
 std::ptrdiff_t index_from_address(Link*& l) const
// compare the addresses of the pointers, rather than values
 { return &l - &head[0]; }
```

Comment: From what I can understand this is a perfect answer to a absolutely reasonable question. Still can't understand why the down and close votes? Anyway, thank you!